For the id primary key field, should the ID type be used as the identifier instead of using a specific String or Int?
When using ID as a type identifier, the same code returns different types in different environments, one environment is String, and the other environment is Int. Should the return value type use a strong type instead of an ID type? Different types will lead to different results for === or some components.

Defining types for ID can be of two types:
If you are looking for Flexibility then you can define ID as ID's
type USER{
id:ID!
name:String!
}

But the problem with this approach is it provides many pitfalls in the development and gives type inconsistency errors when comparing ===
If you are looking for Consistency then you can define your ID as int || string:
type USER{
id:String!
name:String!
}

This is generic approach Ultimately you have to decide the types according to your requirement and database schema.

Yes, I have encountered the problem of inconsistent types, and they behave differently in different environments.

An ID can be just about anything - string, number, etc… my personal preference is to use UUIDs. It's better if the ID is unique for a given type as then it can be used for caching as well as for keys in React (for example).
